# Scala setter and getters

Tags: scala, scala-repl

Considering this trait 'Person' and this class 'PersonImpl':

```
trait Person {

  def name: String
  def surname: String
  def married: Boolean
  def married_=(state: Boolean): Unit

  override def toString(): String = name + " " + surname + " " + married
}

class PersonImpl(override val name: String,
                  override val surname: String,
                  override var married: Boolean) extends Person
```

Using REPL (scala from command line, just open a terminal and type scala) I create the trait and the class. I have the following messages:
-defined Trait Person
-defined class PersonImpl

Then, still from the command line, I type:

- val p: Person = new PersonImpl1("mario", "rossi", false)
- println(p)
- p.married=true
- prinln(p)

I can clearly see that my person has been created and the var field married has been changed from false to true. Allright.
Now I am repeating the same process just with another class and another trait:

```
trait Element {

  def x: Int
  def y: Int
  def width: Int
  def height: Int

  def x_:(i:Int):Unit
  def y_:(i:Int):Unit

  override def toString(): String = x + " " + y + " " + width + " " + height

}

class GameElement(override var x: Int,override var y: Int,override val width: Int,override val height: Int) extends Element
```

As soon as I type the class into the command line I run into the error:
'variable x overrides nothing'

How can this be possible?

Comment: I forgot '=' in Element trait, which is:trait Element {

  def x: Int
  def y: Int
  def width: Int
  def height: Int

  def x_:(i:Int):Unit
  def y_:(i:Int):Unit

  override def toString(): String = x + " " + y + " " + width + " " + height

}

Comment: You've misspelled your setters, compare Element to your working example and you should see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the recommended way to do this in Scala - look into using case classes instead.

but to answer your q you should have `def x_:(i:Int):Unit` changed to def `x_=(i:Int):Unit` same for y